# Magento 2, Add Product in Cart in loop

Tags: magento2, product, cart, addtocart

i have written a small functionality, where i need to get data from XML or CSV and populate the data in the cart.

I am able to read the data from the file and create an array of the items

```
foreach ($products as $productId => $singleQty)
    {

        $product = $this->productModel->load($productId);
        if ($product)
        {
            echo $product->getId() .'<br/>';
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $singleQty));
            $this->cart->save();
        }
    }
```

the echo result is completely fine, it displays the product Ids correctly

But only one item gets added into the cart, with the total number of items.

Suppose i have product IDs 2 and 4 with quantities 200 and 400 respectively,

the above snippet only adds product with ID 2, but the quantity added is 600

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to resolve it by removing the _productModel

```
foreach ($products as $productId => $singleQty)
    {
        $this->_cart->addProduct($productId, array('qty' => $singleQty));
    }
    $this->_cart->save();
```

This works fine

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save cart outside the `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($products as $productId => $singleQty)
{

    $product = $this->productModel->load($productId);
    if ($product)
    {
        echo $product->getId() .'<br/>';
        $this->cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $singleQty));

    }
}

$this->cart->save();
```